# Why is there a result of `#Error` in an Access query with a join on two type-converted fields?

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, type-conversion

I’m getting a result of `#Error`in an Access 2010 query which has a right join on two fields which are type-converted. I can eliminate the error by improving my queries, but I’m confused as to why it happens.

I have the following two tables, T1 and T2. Both consist of an ID field and a text field.

```
T1                  T2
 ID |  F1            ID |  F1 
----+-----          ----+-----
  1 |  zzz            1 |  aaa
  2 |  bbb            2 |  bbb
  3 |  ccc            3 | NULL
```

I then have two simple queries as follows. (Yes, I’m aware they’re not really doing anything productive. I’m simplifying for the sake of the example.)

```
Q1
SELECT [T1].[ID], CStr([T1].[F1]) AS SF1
FROM T1;

Q2
SELECT [T2].[ID], CStr([T2].[F1]) AS SF1
FROM T2;
```

The result sets of these queries are as I expected.

```
Q1                  Q2
 ID | SF1            ID | SF1  
----+-----          ----+-----
  1 | zzz             1 | aaa
  2 | bbb             2 | bbb
  3 | ccc             3 | #Error
```

Then I have one additional query, which is where I run into my confusion.

```
Q3
SELECT [Q1].[ID], [Q1].[SF1], [Q2].[SF1]
FROM Q1 RIGHT JOIN Q2 ON
[Q1].[SF1] = [Q2].[SF1];
```

The results of the third query are not what I expected.

```
Q3 (Actual)
 Q1.ID | Q1.SF1 | Q2.SF1
-------+--------+-------
  NULL | #Error | aaa   
  2    | bbb    | bbb   


Q3 (Expected)
 Q1.ID | Q1.SF1 | Q2.SF1
-------+--------+-------
  NULL | NULL   | aaa   
  2    | bbb    | bbb   
  3    | ccc    | NULL
```

If I replace the CStr function with a ‘non-type-conversion’ function, like Mid, the results are as I would expect.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is really simple. Unlike what Ctznkane says, `CStr(Null)` does not return `Null` since strings can't be `Null` in VBA. Instead, it throws *Run-time error 92: Invalid use of Null*. That's why you get the *#Error*

There are multiple ways to handle this. The most obvious one is to use the `Nz` function (e.g. `Cstr(Nz([T2].[F1]))`). This replaces `Null` with an empty string. However, an empty string is not null, thus `IsNull(Cstr(Nz(Null)))` will return false.

The proper thing to do is actually handle `Null` separately, since a string can't be `Null`:
`IIF([T2].[F1] Is Not Null, CStr([T2].[F1]), Null)`

Comment: I should clarify that I'm using the SQL view in the query designer. I'm not doing this in VBA. And I understand that CStr(Null) does not return Null. I'm confused about the #Error result in the first row of the Q3 results.

Comment: I understand that, but CStr is essentially a VBA function, and thus has these limitations. You're using CStr on a field contrasting Null, and that's why you get the #Error